# href adds symbols to link preventing it from opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I have a very simple href in html code. When I try to click on the link to make sure it works it adds symbols to the link and prevents it from opening.

Lets say the code is:

```
<a href=“/home/readmore.html” > Read More &raquo</a>
```

When the link is clicked, it will try to send you to "â€œ/home/readmore.htmlâ€%C2%9D" instead of “/home/readmore.html”

I'm not quite sure what's going on since this should be such a straight forward command.

Comment: Use single or double quotes only, smart quotes are not allowed in HTML (except as content ofcourse). Which editor are you using?

Comment: I'm using a basic text editor on Mac OS. But you were right, not using smart quotes did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your a tag from:

```
<a href=“/home/readmore.html” > Read More &raquo</a>
```

to:

```
<a href="/home/readmore.html" > Read More &raquo</a>
```